# How to convert Int to Hex string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, integer, numbers, hex, string-formatting

I'm looking for a similar function to Java's `Integer.toHexString()` in Kotlin. Is there something built-in, or we have to manually write a function to convert `Int` to `String`?

Comment: Note: I'm aware that I can use the `Integer` class from Java :) I'm looking for a pure Kotlin approach, if available.

Comment: Most of the kotlin library simply consists in providing extension methods on top of standard Java classes. The language and library are designed to make it easy to use the Java classes. Why won't you use Integer.toHexString? What would an alternate implementation bring, except redundancy?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not against using `Integer.toHexString()` - For example, take a look at the answer that @hotkey provided below. Short and directly accessible from any Int. I can use anything really to complete my task, but I was just looking for something Kotlin-like if available.

Comment: @milosmns, updated the answer. The `toString(radix: Int)` function will still be different because of the unsigned conversion used in `Integer.toHexString()`, so that it won't probably fit you anyway.

Comment: Right, got it. That pretty much answers everything I wanted to know

Comment: So, you want to define an extension method that calls Integer.toHexString()? Not reimplmeent the function in Kotlin? Here it is: `fun Int.toHexString() = Integer.toHexString(this)`

Comment: @JBNizet Yep, that's exactly what I had so far. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can still use the Java conversion by calling the static function on `java.lang.Integer`:

```
val hexString = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(i)
```

And, starting with Kotlin 1.1, there is a function in the Kotlin standard library that does the conversion, too:

> [`fun Int.toString(radix: Int): String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-string.html)
>
> Returns a string representation of this `Int` value in the specified `radix`.

Note, however, that **this will still be different** from `Integer.toHexString()`, because the latter performs the unsigned conversion:

```
println((-50).toString(16)) // -32
println(Integer.toHexString(-50)) // ffffffce
```

But with experimental [Kotlin unsigned types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#unsigned-integers), it is now possible to get the same result from negative number unsigned conversion as with `Integer.toHexString(-50)`:

```
println((-50).toUInt().toString(16)) // ffffffce
```

Comment: You can get the same results as `Integer.toHexString()` by converting to long first: `(-50).toLong().toString(16)` returns `ffffffce`. Also, there is `UInt` and `ULong` now, so for a long, you could use `toULong().toString(16)`.

Answer (score 25):

You can simply do it like this:
`"%x".format(1234)`

Comment: And you can also use `"%X".format(1234)` if you want the hex string outputted in all caps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? (I'm new learning kotlin)

Answer (score 24):

If you need to add zero before bytes which less than 10(hex), for example you need string - "0E" then use:
 `"%02x".format(14)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new Kotlin 1.9.0 standard library [`HexFormat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-hex-format.html):
(don't forget to add `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)` where needed)

```kotlin
val myHexFormat = HexFormat {
    upperCase = false
    number.prefix = "#"
    number.removeLeadingZeros = true
}
val myInt = 0xb40e89
myInt.toHexString(myHexFormat)         // #b40e89
```

You could also use the Kotlin predefined `HexFormat`s:

```kotlin
val myInt = 0xb40e89
myInt.toHexString(HexFormat.Default)   // 00b40e89
myInt.toHexString(HexFormat.UpperCase) // 00B40E89
```

---

To exclude the alpha from an ARGB integer, do this workaround:

```kotlin
(myInt and 0xFFFFFF).toHexString(myHexFormat)
```

And vote for this issue: [Cannot ignore alpha when formatting with HexFormat](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60787)