# How to convert epoch timestamp to unix hex timestamp in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, unix-timestamp, epoch

I am using the following code to get the current epoch time in kotlin.

```
val epochTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
```

Output: 1628769521313

And now the question is how can I convert this timestamp to Unix hex timestamp (https://www.epochconverter.com/hex)

Thank you in advance

Comment: A Unix timestamp — also the one in your link — is in seconds, not milliseconds since the Unix epoch. So you probably want `Instant.now().toEpochSecond()`rather than `toEpochMilli()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is required as far as I can see is that the decimal epoch output needs to be converted into a hexidecimal string.

This can be achieved simply by

`"%X".format(1628769521313)`.

this was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736097/2199001). You can see many other ways of doing the same thing in that question too.